# How to install Kivy on Windows?

Tags: python, kivy

I have downloaded the package 'Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64' from their website. I extracted it and gives me a folder with gstreamer, kivy34, MinGW, etc. As I have searched to some tutorials I clicked the kivy-3.4.bat file to set the paths. Now I'm lost, what to do next?

I wanted to do Kivy applications through Python IDLE. Help!

Comment: Oh look, my friend google's top result: http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: I've already done that still I cannot run it

Comment: Then you've done something wrong, your question should not be "how to i install a application on windows", it should clearly state ALL the things you've tried, what happens when you try to run it. Maybe then we can help you, i still think this is general computer problem solving tho.

Comment: Can you state step-by-step guide after download the package?

Comment: You should do what Torxed said, but just an observation; I don't think IDLE is installed in kivy's packaged environment because it's quite big (but I think you need it there because it's tied to a python installation). You can probably install it if you want, but it's not actually that popular outside of being useful for beginners, and you might find this a good time to try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have PIP installed (it gives the option to install when you download python). Then, open a command shell (CMD on Windows; enter the search bar and type in 'cmd') and type `pip install kivy`.

Some would recommend setting up a virtualenv and stuff but as a quick answer this should work.